# How can I dynamically access a field of a field of a structure in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I'm interested in the general problem of accessing a field which may be buried an arbitrary number of levels deep in a containing structure.  A concrete example using two levels is below.

Say I have a structure `toplevel`, which I define from the MATLAB command line with the following:

```
midlevel.bottomlevel = 'foo';
toplevel.midlevel = midlevel;
```

I can access the `midlevel` structure by passing the field name as a string, e.g.:

```
fieldnameToAccess = 'midlevel';
value = toplevel.(fieldnameToAccess);
```

but I can't access the `bottomlevel` structure the same way -- the following is not valid syntax:

```
fieldnameToAccess = 'midlevel.bottomlevel';
value = toplevel.(fieldnameToAccess); %# throws ??? Reference to non-existent field 'midlevel.bottomlevel'
```

I could write a function that looks through `fieldnameToAccess` for periods and then recursively iterates through to get the desired field, but I am wondering if there's some clever way to use MATLAB built-ins to just get the field value directly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would have to split the dynamic field accessing into two steps for your example, such as:

```
>> field1 = 'midlevel';
>> field2 = 'bottomlevel';
>> value = toplevel.(field1).(field2)

value =

foo
```

However, there is a way you can generalize this solution for a string with an arbitrary number of subfields delimited by periods. You can use the function [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) to extract the field names from the string and the function [GETFIELD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getfield.html) to perform the recursive field accessing in one step:

```
>> fieldnameToAccess = 'midlevel.bottomlevel';
>> fields = textscan(fieldnameToAccess,'%s','Delimiter','.');
>> value = getfield(toplevel,fields{1}{:})

value =

foo
```

Comment: Is there a way to append the fieldnameToAccess to the end of a variable, ie. toplevel.(fields{1}{1}).(fields{1}{2})=resample(getfield(toplevel,fields{1}{:}),...); in a general way (without knowing there are only 2 levels)?